# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar mi sitio web solo en una ciudad?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, typescript, angular

¿Cómo puedo mostrar mi sitio web solo en una ciudad?

El cliente solo quiere ser visto en una ciudad en todo el mundo, ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?, les agradecería mucho su ayuda :)

---

Hice lo que me dijiste:

https://i.gyazo.com/5c933886ffd28e8287d803c094574009.png

y me manda este error:

> ```
> array ( 'geoplugin_request' => '::1', 'geoplugin_status' => 404, 'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.', 'geoplugin_city' => NULL, 'geoplugin_region' => NULL, 'geoplugin_areaCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_dmaCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_countryCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_countryName' => NULL, 'geoplugin_continentCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_latitude' => NULL, 'geoplugin_longitude' => NULL, 'geoplugin_regionCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_regionName' => '', 'geoplugin_currencyCode' => NULL, 'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => NULL, 'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => '', 'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '0', )
> ```

Comment: Creo que se podría obtener el ip del visitante, verificar su ubicación y luego según esta realizar un direccionamiento

Comment: Debes conectarte a una interface de red que no sea la local, es decir, subir tu aplicacion a un servidor, pues esa es tu IP actual, solo que en formato ipv6.

Comment: Yo conozco una forma de volver tu router un servidor, abriendo puertos y configurando xampp para que permita usar tu IP REAL como servidor, pero tiene sus desventajas. En el caso de ser de producción el caso es distinto, podrias preguntar como hacer de tu equipo un servidor, y asi realizar las pruebas de los ip, porque como estas en local te saldra solo la tuya, a menos que configures tu router para recibir solicitudes y obtengas los IP

Comment: Uno de los problemas de usar tu router seria que a la hora de que reinicies la maquina deberias volver a habilitar las IP estaticas para que entren y salgan las peticiones, desbloquear tu firewall, y asignar permisos a los puertos.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Actualizado en base al comentario de Alfredo Paz

En el caso de PHP podrías recurrir a lo siguiente:

**1)** Obtener la direccion IP del visitante.

```
<?php
function get_real_ip() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
echo $mi_ip = get_real_ip();
?>
```

**2)** Llamar a un servicio de geolocalizacion, en este caso *http://www.geoplugin.net*:

```
$datos_cliente = var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$mi_ip)));
```

**3)** Utilizar los valores del objeto obtenido:

```
array (
  'geoplugin_request' => '100.100.100.100',
  'geoplugin_status' => 200,
  'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.',
  'geoplugin_city' => 'Ciudad',
  'geoplugin_region' => 'Region\',
  'geoplugin_areaCode' => '0',
  'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '0',
  'geoplugin_countryCode' => 'PA',
  'geoplugin_countryName' => 'Pais',
  'geoplugin_continentCode' => 'Co',
  'geoplugin_latitude' => '0.000',
  'geoplugin_longitude' => '-0.000',
  'geoplugin_regionCode' => '00',
  'geoplugin_regionName' => 'Region,
  'geoplugin_currencyCode' => 'COD',
  'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => NULL,
  'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => '',
  'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '0',
)
```

**4)** Asignar la ciudad y verificar que sea la ciudad permitida

```
$ciudad_permitida= "Santa Lucia";
$ciudad_cliente = $datos_cliente["geoplugin_city"];
if($ciudad_cliente == $ciudad_permitida){
    header("location index.php");
} else {
    header("location error_ciudad_prohibida.php");
}
```

**5)** Tu pagina de error

```
<html>
<h1>Este sitio web esta bloqueado para tu localidad</h1>
</html>
```

**6)** Completo seria algo como:

```
<?php
function get_real_ip() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$mi_ip = get_real_ip();


$datos_cliente = var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$mi_ip)));

$ciudad_permitida = "Santa Lucia";

$ciudad_cliente = $datos_cliente["geoplugin_city"];

if($ciudad_cliente == $ciudad_permitida){
    header("location index.php");
} else {
    header("location error_ciudad_prohibida.php");
}
?>
```

> Cabe destacar que podrias obtener la IP desde donde obtiene
>   internet el usuario, ubicandolo en una ciudad distinta.

**Nota:** Cambie el código para que tomaras la ciudad permitida en vez de ir revisando todas las ciudades que NO pueden ser validas.

> Acoto que si tu ciudad se llama ejemplo "barcelona", podrías encontrar
>   personas que accederían de España y desde Venezuela, tendrías que
>   agregar tambien la condición de tu pais.

### Actualizado para verificar el pais y la ciudad de procedencia:

Agrego el codigo verificando tambien el pais de procedencia evitando conflictos de una misma ciudad, por ejemplo: Venezuela y España tienen una ciudad llamada Barcelona

```
$pais_permitido = "Venezuela";
$ciudad_permitida= "Barcelona";

$pais_cliente = $datos_cliente["geoplugin_countryName"];
$ciudad_cliente = $datos_cliente["geoplugin_city"];

if($pais_cliente == $pais_permitido and
   $ciudad_cliente == $ciudad_permitida){
    header("location index.php");
} else {
    header("location error_ciudad_prohibida.php");
}
```

En este caso primero verificamos que el cliente este en Venezuela y segundo que sea la ciudad barcelona.

### Actualizado en base al comentario de Adriá Vilanova

Cito su comentario:

> Como sugerencia, estaría bien mencionar que los servicios de
>   geolocalización de IP son poco precisos y que además algunas veces
>   fallan muy significativamente. Por ejemplo, si vives en una ciudad
>   cercana a Madrid (pongamos a modo de ejemplo Alcalá de Henares), puede
>   que el servicio de geolocalización de IPs diga que está en Madrid. Por
>   eso creo que no es un método de control de seguridad perfecto, y creo
>   que debería quedar indicado en la respuesta para aquellas personas que
>   desconocen esto

Comment: pero en realidad debe bloquear absolutamente todas las ciudades menos la que su cliente le esta indicando, entonces solo debería comprobar que la IP que llega sea de la zona permitida y que el cualquier otro caso rechace la petición si no sería demasiado código

Comment: Genial, la respuesta fue un prototipo mental, muy buena sugerencia

Comment: Muchas Gracias vaavDev, x tu explicación trataré de ponerla en  practica y decirle al cliente que si se puede, pero en realidad nose porque no quiere aparecer en más ciudades, si asi puede generar mas clientes, y también gracias a Alfredo Paz, por tu sugerencia, saludos

Comment: @MoisésAguilar de nada hermano cualquier duda publica aqui, por cierto dale un positivo al comentario de Alfredo, en la flechita a la derecha del uno

Comment: Listo, respecto a lo q dijsite en la ultima nota, si acceden desde algun lugar de españa, que no sea barcelona, no podran ver el sitio, eso tambien esta en el código no?

Comment: @MoisésAguilar verifica de nuevo la respuesta, la he actualizado

Comment: wow! Excelente! Agregado a favorito!

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, lo verificare, es de gran ayuda tu aporte

Comment: Asi es Einer, una respuesta muy bien explicada.

Comment: Como la agrego a favoritos la respuesta, soy nuevo en StackOverflow, de echo la cree hace como 1 hr jeje

Comment: Como sugerencia, estaría bien mencionar que los servicios de geolocalización de IP son poco precisos y que además algunas veces fallan muy significativamente. Por ejemplo, si vives en una ciudad cercana a Madrid (pongamos a modo de ejemplo Alcalá de Henares), puede que el servicio de geolocalización de IPs diga que está en Madrid. Por eso creo que no es un método de control de seguridad perfecto, y creo que debería quedar indicado en la respuesta para aquellas personas que desconocen esto.

Comment: @AdriàVilanova Gracias por tu aporte, ya agregue el comentario a la respuesta

Comment: Porque nadamas me muestra el páis??

Comment: @MoisésAguilar podrias publicar el codigo que estas usando en la pregunta como una actualizacion

Answer (score 7):

**1**
Agrego a la respuesta aceptada la forma de obtener la ip que me ha funcionado teniendo en cuenta proxies, loadbalancers y demás:

```
function get_ip_address()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');

    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    if (strpos($ipaddress, ",") !== false) :
      $ipaddress = strtok($ipaddress, ",");
    endif;
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Nótese que en las últimas líneas descarto las ip extra agregadas cuando la petición pasa por varios proxies (puede no ser la ip real si por seguridad se descarta en el proxy pero es una buena aproximación).

**2**
Haciendo pruebas en entornos locales y detrás de routers, balancers o nat la ip reportada será la local con lo cual un geoip location dara error, para subsanar esto usamos el siguiente truco:

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
$externalIp = $m[1];
```

**3** 
Tener en cuenta que servicios como geoplugin son gratis hasta 150/200 peticiones/consultas por minuto, esto puede ser aceptable para una web de bajo tráfico a normal, pero si se realiza una campaña de marketing con una fecha límite lo mas probable es que en las primeras horas el servidor reciba muchas consultas simultáneas y falle.
Para evitar esto último tendrás que:

a) bajarte tu propia copia de geolite database

```
 $ wget -c -N http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.tar.gz
 $ tar -zxvf GeoLite2-City.tar.gz
```

b) instalar una librería para usarla. (PHP usando composer https://getcomposer.org/)

```
 $ composer require geoip2/geoip2
```

c) usar la librería:

```
require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$GEOIP_DBCITY = __DIR__ .'/app/cache/GeoLite2-City.mmdb';

$theIP = '8.8.8.8';
try {
    $reader = new Reader($GEOIP_DBCITY);
    $record = $reader->city($theIP);
    echo 'Country : '.$record->country->name.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'State   : '.$record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'City    : '.$record->city->name.PHP_EOL;
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Something went wrong : '.$ex->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Nota: el uso de esta librería puede llegar a requerir instalar extensiones extra de php (bcmath o gmp por ejemplo)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Excelente aporte!