# Al detectar IP en PHP me muestra "::1"

Tags: php, ip, wamp

Mi duda es si es posible utilizar las IP's publicas en un servidor local, yo utilizo WAMP, esto lo requiero para hacer unas pruebas en las que utilizo las IP's detectadas ya que como pueden saber los servidores locales no detectan las IP's publicas, al intentar hacerlo me muestra **::1**. Quisiera que el ultimo recurso fuera subirlo a host. Si les sirve de algo el lenguaje que estoy utilizando es PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano en la respuesta dada, aunque es muy completa no veo que extraiga la ip externa(pública) de un servidor local. =)

Comment: @aloMalbarez eso es precisamente lo que hace el código, extraer la IP externa... a no ser que se entienda otra cosa por IP externa pública *de un servidor local*. ¿No sé exactamente a qué se referiría lo de *servidor local*. Tu llamada a `http://checkip.dyndns.com/` daría el mismo resultado que arroja la llamada a la API de la respuesta indicada más arriba, sólo que la información que aquella arroja es más completa. Si lo único que interesa es la IP, bastaría con llamar a la función `get_client_ip`.

Comment: justamente en la respuesta dada `get_client_ip` usa las variables del sistema, que como es servidor local (WAMP segun OP) le va a dar `"::1"` ver el caso de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156870/81450, al aplicar la respuesta le surge el mismo problema, lo cual motivo el punto 2 de mi respuesta complementaria, código que usé en esta misma respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma es "preguntar la IP pública" a un servidor externo.

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
$externalIp = $m[1];
```

Añado script que devuelve tanto la IP detectada del cliente (el navegador), como la IP pública del servidor (local) donde reside el script

```
<?php

function get_client_ip() {
  $ipaddress = '';
  if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');

  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');

  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
     $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');

  else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
  else
      $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
  if (strpos($ipaddress, ",") !== false) :
    $ipaddress = strtok($ipaddress, ",");
  endif;
  return $ipaddress;
}

function get_public_ip(){
  $externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
  preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
  $externalIp = $m[1];
  return $externalIp;
}

$theIP = get_client_ip();
$theExternalIP = get_public_ip();
?>
<p><?php echo 'Detected Client IP : '.$theIP.PHP_EOL;?></p>
<p><?php echo 'Detected (Local) External IP : '.$theExternalIP.PHP_EOL;?></p>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que estan realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayudanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Disiento, la pregunta es clara y directa. de hecho en el enlace hay un ejemplo parecido :
"Bien: ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP?"

Comment: Revisar [ask] y [answer].

Comment: @Jorgesys me da la sensación que hay un problema de comprensión del título, correr el ejemplo en un servidor local y ver las diferencias entre IP pública de un servidor local (lo que se pregunta) y obtener la dirección del cliente (lo que responde la pregunta marcada como duplicada)

Comment: He revisado la otra pregunta de la que dicen que ésta está duplicada y pues la verdad por lo que veo no resuelve mi problema, pues como ya dije mi problema consiste en que al utilizar X script para sacar la ip me muestra *::1*.

Comment: @Jalkhov para estar seguros, lo que necesitas es la ip externa o pública (vista desde internet) del servidor local? probaste el script de ejemplo?

Comment: La ip con la que se conecta el cliente, o sea la pública, he corrido el script y en la ip del cliente me sigue mostrando ::1, pero en la externa si me arroja un resultado, y esa si es mi ip ¿Por que sucede ésto? ¿No deberían ser la misma?

Comment: si y no, al acceder con un navegador (local) a un servidor local estas accediendo desde "`::1`" a "`::1`" o en otras palabras de localhost a localhost. si el servidor local estuviera también escuchando en la placa de red verías la ip local de la placa de red, para obtener la direción pública tenes que dar la vuelta por otro servidor y preguntar desde afuera. esto mismo pasa si tu servidor "local" está en una maquina y accedes desde otra máquina en la misma red, vas a ver como ip del cliente la dirección local de la computadora del navegador (en el rango `fe80::/10`)

Comment: una duda: para que necesitas la IP pública? en las preguntas relacionadas se utiliza para hacer geoip (el cual falla si el script está en un servidor local)