# ¿Por qué no puedo ver mi sitio web si tengo configurado el archivo .htaccess de esta manera?

Tags: php, mysql, web, apache, .htaccess

```
order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from <mi ip privada>
```

A no ser que esté poniendo mal mi IP pero no creo, la he comprobado muchas veces, y la IP la extraje escribiendo este comando (subrayado en rojo), la cual supuestamente es la que aparece en la línea marcada en verde. Todo ello lo hice siguiendo tutoriales.
Lo que pretendo es que momentaneamente sólo yo pueda ver mi sitio web y no funciona, ni en local ni en un servidor gratuito (000webhost) que estoy usando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Disculpen si no estoy usando de buena manera stackoverflow, es mi primer post en este sitio.

Comment: salvo q estes directamente conectado a tu isp `ipconfig` te va a dar la ip de red local ( NAT por lo general, en el rango 192.168.x.y ). en entorno local dependerá de como sea el binding del servicio a las interfaces, en el caso de servidor de internet la ip que recibirá es la ip pública que te asignó tu proveedor de internet (isp) para ver la diferencia de ip trabajando en local revisa el script en esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175800/81450

Comment: Con el script del enlace que compartiste me inventé una solución temporal y quizá rudimentaria, que igual por ahí para un experto puede parecer un candado de cartón pero para gente normal como el personal de esa empresa (que es al fin y al cabo lo que importa) puede funcionar tranquilamente. 

Mil gracias hermano.