# Saben cómo obtener la ip con php

Tags: php, html

Este es mi código
Al Mostar el resultado me muestra un for= antes de la ip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Obtiene la IP del cliente
    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }
?>

<?php
include("geoiploc.php");
    $ip =get_client_ip(); 
?> 
Tu dirección IP es: <?php echo($ip); ?> <br>
Tu País es : <?php echo(getCountryFromIP($ip, " NamE"));?>
 (<?php echo(getCountryFromIP($ip, "code"));?>)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate si funciona con esta variación del `get_client_ip()` https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/156963/81450

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias.